# Converting a integer number with 'E' to a normal view in PHP

Tags: php, formatting

a rookie question.
does anybody know how to convert a number output like  7.3558275113866E+15 to convenient view like 7355827511386687544321... having no 'E' in its written form?
many thanks for your comment in advance.

Comment: Number format: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: `sprintf("%f", 7.3558275113866E+15)`